# Wordpress 3.5: own gallery with included images doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-3.5

I just updated to Wordpress 3.5, but this crashed a little part of my code:
There is a php file, which loads a specific post with its gallery via AJAX.

The code looks like:

```
<?php

// Include WordPress
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../../../wp-load.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];

// query post with this identifier
query_posts('meta_key=identifier&meta_value='.$id); 
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    // add content
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content()); 
    echo '<div class="content-inner">'.$content.'</div>';
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

The post contains a [gallery] shortcode. I've build my own Wordpress gallery with this code:

```
remove_shortcode('gallery');
add_shortcode('gallery', 'parse_gallery_shortcode');

function parse_gallery_shortcode($atts) {

    global $post;

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'orderby' => 'menu_order ASC, ID ASC',
        'id' => $post->ID,
        'itemtag' => 'dl',
        'icontag' => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns' => 3,
        'size' => 'full',
        'link' => 'file'
    ), $atts));

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_parent' => $id,
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby' => $orderby
        ); 

    $images = get_posts($args);
    print_r($images);
}
```

This works with all other galleries on my site, but not with the ajax-loaded ones. And it has worked with Wordpress 3.4.

Are there changes in Wordpress 3.5 that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out: If you use a gallery with images, which are already uploaded to the media library, the gallery shortcode looks like `[gallery ids=1,2,3]`, what means, that images are only linked (and not attached) to the gallery, so `post_type=attachment` doesn't work.

Now i'm using regular expressions to get the image IDs:

```
$post_content = $post->post_content;
preg_match('/\[gallery.*ids=.(.*).\]/', $post_content, $ids);
$array_id = explode(",", $ids[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible to pull all the [galleries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_galleries) or even a single [gallery](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery) using the `$post->ID` and [`get_post_galleries()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_galleries). Each gallery will contain the image id list in `ids` as well as a list of the [image urls](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_galleries_images) in `src`. The gallery object is basically the shortcode arguments so you have access to those as well.

```
if ( $galleries = get_post_galleries( $post->ID, false ) ) {

    $defaults = array (
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ASC, ID ASC',
        'id'         => $post->ID,
        'itemtag'    => 'dl',
        'icontag'    => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'full',
        'link'       => 'file',
        'ids'        => "",
        'src'        => array (),
    );

    foreach ( $galleries as $gallery ) {

        // defaults
        $args = wp_parse_args( $gallery, $defaults );

        // image ids
        $args[ 'ids' ] = explode( ',', $args[ 'ids' ] );

        // image urls
        $images = $args[ 'src' ];
    }
}
```