# Wordpress 4.1 Gallery Shortcode Sorting

Tags: wordpress, gallery, shortcode

I know there are several questions on here regarding the sorting of Wordpress shortcode galleries, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832172/wordpress-3-5-2-gallery-order-problems), but no solutions I have found seem to work.  I am creating a gallery on a page template that includes images from galleries in a custom post-type.  I have that portion working, and have the gallery being created with the page template, however, the images keep ordering by ID, ascending.

The function I have created adds the image IDs to the gallery shortcode in chronological order by post date, newest to oldest.  I have echoed the ids attribute to verify and receive the output: 177, 239, 236, 235, 234, 232, 230, 231.  However, when the images appear in the gallery, they are listed as 177, 230, 231, 232, 234, 235, 236, and 239.  The gallery shortcode states, `// 'ids' is explicitly ordered, unless you specify otherwise.`, however this is clearly not happening.

I have attempted specifying the order and orderby attributes in the shortcode, using, `orderby='post__in'` and `order='ASC'`
as well as creating a new gallery shortcode for this specific page and making the suggested changes in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832172/wordpress-3-5-2-gallery-order-problems).  Neither of these have made any affect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

---UPDATE---

As requested, here are the code snippets.  This is the function that forms the gallery shortcode for the template file.  I have added a new shortcode of [portfolio_gallery] so I can modify that, and still use the standard [gallery] shortcode elsewhere.

```
function portfolio_slider_images($post_id) {
    $size=large;
    $num=1;


    $cat = get_post_meta($post_id, 'portfolio_category', true);

//Query Args
$query_args = array('post_type' => 'portfolio'); 

//Query posts of portfolio_type with proper category
$posts = new WP_Query($query_args);
//$posts= query_posts(array('taxonomy'=>'portfolio_type', 'slug'=>$cat, 'post_type' => 'portfolio'));

//Count to track initial ID added to shortcode
$count = 0;  

//Start gallery shortcode - using new shortcode [portfolio_gallery]
$gallery= '[portfolio_gallery columns="3" size="medium" link="file" data-rel="lightbox" ids="';

//Cycle through each post that met requirements
while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
//foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    echo($post->ID. " "); 
            $categories = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'portfolio_type');
            foreach($categories as $category){
                if($category->slug == $cat){
        //Check for gallery in post, if present, take those images
                    if ( get_post_gallery($post->ID) ){ 
                        $post_gallery = get_post_gallery( $post->ID , false );
                        if($count == 0){$gallery = $gallery . $post_gallery['ids'];}
                        else{$gallery = $gallery . ', '. $post_gallery['ids'];}
        }
        //If no gallery in post, pull images attached to post
                    else if ( $images = get_children(array(
                            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                            'post_type' => 'attachment',
                            'numberposts' => $num,
                            'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))
                    {
                            $incount = 1;
                            foreach( $images as $image ) {
                                    if ($incount == $num) {$incount= 1;}
                                    if($count == 0){$gallery = $gallery . $image->ID;}
                                    else{$gallery = $gallery . ', '. $image->ID;}
                                    $incount++;
                            }
                    }
        //If no images, do nothing  - echo left from testing 
        else {
                            //echo "No Image";
                    }
                    $count++;
                }
            }
    endwhile;        
//}
//Close out gallery shortcode
    $gallery = $gallery . '"]';

//echo($gallery);
    echo('<div class="portfolio-gallery">'.do_shortcode($gallery).'</div');
    //wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();
```

}

The code for the [portfolio_gallery] shortcode is presently identical to that for the [gallery] shortcode in the media.php file.  The changes I have attempted for that function did not correct the ordering.  In the above block, I have tried adding the `orderby='post__in' order='ASC'` as well as any other orderby listings.  None of these have changed the order of the images.

Hopefully these additions help.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the relevant code snippets?

Comment: Code snippet added.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you check if the same happens when you use the `[portfolio_gallery ids="..."]` shortcode in the post content editor? PS: You shouldn't use `query_posts()`, it can give all kinds of problem. Try `WP_Query()` or `get_posts()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the note regarding `query_posts()`.  I have updated the code to now use `WP_Query()` and am receiving the same result.  When I use the same image IDs and the `[portfolio_gallery]` in a regular page, I am receiving the same issues.  I have tried using `orderby="post__in" order="ASC"` and `DESC`,  as well as `orderby="ID" order="DESC"`.  I still am having the gallery display in ascending order by ID.

Comment: So the problem seems to be within the `[portfolio_gallery]` shortcode, but it's not clear how you define it. I guess the ids-ordering is working for the native `[gallery ids="..."]` shortcode? Ps: Regarding the `query_posts()` function, check out [this note](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) from the Codex.

Comment: To define the `[portfolio_gallery]` shortcode, I placed `add_shortcode('portfolio_gallery', 'custom_gallery_shortcode');` in the functions.php file with the function `custom_gallery_shortcode($attr)` directly after.  Presently, the content of that function is identical to that in the original `gallery_shortcode()` function.  I simply created this other shortcode so I could make changes without having it affect any other galleries currently in use.  I just test the `[gallery ids="..."]` shortcode, using the `orderby="ID" order="DESC"` and `orderby="post__in" order="ASC"` with no luck. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried `[gallery ids="496,479,330" orderby="ID" order="DESC"]` and `[gallery ids="330,479,496" orderby="ID" order="DESC"]`, where I got exactly the same output for both shortcodes, on the default TwentyFifteen theme. If that's not working for you, then maybe some plugin or theme is interfering with the native gallery shortcode?

Comment: Thank you very much.  It was a plugin.  I thought I went through them all to ensure they were not affecting the ordering, however, I must have missed one.  I went back and tested them after your last comment.  Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Glad to hear it's resolved.