# Get all gallery images / attachments from a post in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, gallery, attachment

## What I need:

1. User uploads pictures in a **gallery** via `WordPress Media
   Uploader` and publishes them in a post. Let's say `post_id = 1` and the post is: 
   `[gallery ids"1,2,3,...,n"]`
2. I need a function that gets all image-ids of `post_id = 1` in this gallery.
3. The images should be liked to '.../post-title/attachment/image-title'

## I've tried  :

```
$attachements = query_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',  
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,   
        'posts_per_page' => -1        
         )
);

var_dump($attachements);
```

My output is:

```
array(0) { }
```

Am I just too stupid?

Answer (score 1):

[`get_post_galleries()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_galleries) can be used to get information about each gallery in the post. Make sure to pass `false` after the `$post_id` to return just the data.

From that point you can loop through the different galleries and pull the `ids` from the `ids` key. This is actually a string so you'll need to [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it into an array that you'll use with [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to add to a total list of `ids`.

Since it's possible to contain duplicate `ids`, running [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) will ensure each `id` is listed only once.

```
$post_id = 298;

$image_ids = array ();

// get all the galleries in the post
if ( $galleries = get_post_galleries( $post_id, false ) ) {

    foreach ( $galleries as $gallery ) {

        // pull the ids from each gallery
        if ( ! empty ( $gallery[ 'ids' ] ) ) {

            // merge into our final list
            $image_ids = array_merge( $image_ids, explode( ',', $gallery[ 'ids' ] ) );
        }
    }
}

// make the values unique
$image_ids = array_unique( $image_ids );    

// convert the ids to urls -- $gallery[ 'src' ] already holds this info
$image_urls = array_map( "wp_get_attachment_url", $image_ids );    

// ---------------------------- //

echo '<pre>';
print_r ( $image_ids );
print_r ( $image_urls );
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
 $args = array( 
'post_type' => 'attachment', 
'numberposts' => -1, 
'post_status' => null, 
'post_parent' => $page->ID);

$attachments = get_posts( $args );
var_dump($attachements);
```

Comment: Output is `NULL`. :-(

Comment: when user uploads an image, you need to attach that image to the post you want. This code will work for images attached to a post.

Comment: this is the plugin to attach images to the post http://wordpress.org/plugins/unattach/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but it was not exactly what I needed.

I replaced the WordPress [gallery]-shortcode with my own function.

https://gist.github.com/3xken/6593568

Comment: And here is an other (better) solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277794/wordpress-3-5-own-gallery-with-included-images-doesnt-work

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with get_post_galleries?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_galleries