# WordPress: Use shortcode_atts in other function

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery, shortcode, posting

Is it possible to use variables from `shortcode_atts` in another function? Here is my idea:

## Posting

[gallery ids="1,2,3,...n"]

## Function get_gallery_ids()

```
//get the gallery-ID's from post
function get_gallery_ids($atts) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
'ids'   => ''
), $atts));
return $ids;
}
```

## Function explode_ids()

```
//example function with ids
function explode_ids($ids) {
$ids = explode(',' $ids);
}
```

How do I implement it? The return just echos.

### Update

The code above is a part of my own new gallery_shortcode.

```
remove_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');
add_shortcode('gallery', 'get_gallery_ids');
```

Comment: Are you rewriting the *gallery* shortcode? Is `get_gallery_ids` the callback of your shortcode? I suppose you'll have to dig into WP [`shortcodes.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/shortcodes.php) file and tweak some of its functions to your own.

Comment: Thank you, and yes, I'm rewriting the gallery shortcode. I went through the code, but WordPress saves their return in §output . = value. ... $output . = "<br />" ... return $output;
Is there no better way?

Comment: Research at [wordpress.se], check this results: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=gallery%20shortcode%20is%3aq

Comment: It helped. Thank you! I researched and somebody had a similar problem and the answer was solved by a link back to stackoverflow. Funny!
This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277794/wordpress-3-5-own-gallery-with-included-images-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

I have an Idea:

I use examples from the WordPress Codex
http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    global $post;   // this is new
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'foo' => 'something',
    'bar' => 'something else',
), $atts ) );
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "gallery_used_atts", $atts); // this is new

return "foo = {$foo}";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

now you are able to get the $atts you are using on a specific post or page by

```
$att_values = get_post_meta( $post_id, "gallery_used_atts", true );
```

and then you can use them for whatever you want.